# Error parsing cmd line options: error parsing uri: URI with srv must not include port number when importing MongoDB collection into remote database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, collections, terminal

I copied the exact command from Atlas into my Terminal for importing my MongoDB collection:

mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://docuCentralAdmin:@documentary-central.5m2dl.mongodb.net/ --collection  --type  --file

...and updated it with my project information:

mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://docuCentralAdmin: Password1138@documentary-central.5m2dl.mongodb.net/docu-centralDB> --collection documentaries --type json --file /Users/lisa/Desktop/documentaries.json

But no matter what get this error. Can anyone advise how I can solve it please?

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue but what i did was to copy my files and put them in the same folder that has my mongoimport file then open that folder with command line then you paste the command below and fill in you as apropriately
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://balix-emma-12:@zomatoapp-40.wv2opsg.mongodb.net/ --collection  --type  --file